# Problema ao salvar nome do método e linha da Exception com StackTrace

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, xamarin-forms, stack-trace

Desenvolvi um método que retorna o `StackTrace` de uma `Exception`, onde consigo saber qual local que aconteceu o erro e qual linha. Em modo Debug ele está funcionando corretamente retorna todas as informações, Porém fora de *debug* ele não retorna as informações.

os métodos usados são o `StackFrame.GetFileName()` e o `StackFrame.GetFileLineNumber()`.

Alguém sabe o motivo? Não encontrei nada na internet sobre isso.

O projeto é em Xamarin Forms com C#.

Esta é a função que chamo passando a `Exception` que retornar um `StackFrame` contendo as informações do local e linha onde ocorreu o erro:

```
public StackFrame getInformacoesExceptionError(Exception ex)
    {
        DateTime dataLogInicio = DateTime.Now;
        try
        {
            StackTrace stackT = new StackTrace(ex, true);
            var sf = stackT.GetFrame(stackT.FrameCount - 1);

            return sf;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            var usuario = getUsuarioBDLocal;
            if (usuario.ErrorLogAtivo)
            {
                StackTrace stackT = new StackTrace(ex, true); 
                var sf = stackT.GetFrame(stackT.FrameCount - 1);

                string instrucaoError = "Error Exception: " + exc.Message + " Line error: " + sf.GetFileLineNumber();
                _logEventoAPI.SaveLogEvento(usuario.IDEmpresa, "APP", DeviceInfo.Model + " | " + DeviceInfo.Manufacturer, usuario.Nome, sf.GetFileName(), dataLogInicio, DateTime.Now, instrucaoError, App.CurrentConfiguration.WebApiAddress);
            }

            return new StackFrame();
        }
    }
```

Aqui o `catch` onde utilizo o `StackFrame` e mando a informação para o banco de dados:

```
 catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var usuario = App.Current.getUsuarioBDLocal;
            if (usuario.ErrorLogAtivo)
            {
                var sf = App.Current.getInformacoesExceptionError(ex);

                string instrucaoError = "Error Exception: " + ex.Message + " Line error: " + sf.GetFileLineNumber();
                var idLogErro = _logEventoAPI.SaveLogEvento(usuario.IDEmpresa, "APP", DeviceInfo.Model + " | " + DeviceInfo.Manufacturer, usuario.Nome, sf.GetFileName(), dataLogInicio, DateTime.Now, instrucaoError, App.CurrentConfiguration.WebApiAddress);

               await _page.DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Aconteceu algo inesperado ! Recarregue a pagina. \r\n\nCaso a mensagem persista entre em contato com nosso suporte e informe o seguinte Cod: " + idLogErro, "Ok");
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=net-7.0  *"StackTrace information will be most informative with Debug build configurations. By default, Debug builds include debug symbols, while **Release builds do not**"* ou seja, Release não tem os *symbols* que são usados para identificar linha, métodos, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O motivo é que estes métodos só funcionam adequadamente em mode *debug*. Eles foram criados para usar nessa situação, não em outras.

Esses dados são obtidos através dos símbolos armazenados no arquivo `.pdb` gerado pelo compilador quando está em modo *debug*. Não existindo isso não tem como obter a informação. Então mesmo em modo *debug* pode não ser capaz de fornecer o que deseja, se o arquivo não foi criado por alguma razão (configuração por exemplo). Em alguns casos pode estar configurado para não ter todas as informações necessárias.

A exceção já tem um [*stack trace*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.stacktrace?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#system-exception-stacktrace) para usar e parece mais precisa, não vi muita necessidade em criar isso, e parece que isso cria alguns problemas, mas esse não é o foco da pergunta, não importa.

Sempre que for usar algo, consulte a [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).